# TypeError: cannot read property "temp" of undefined when retreiving API data

Tags: javascript

I'm using OpenWeatherAPI and React to make a weather app for practie, I'm able to retrieve my date data, but my temp data is giving some issues and I'm not totally sure why. Here is my error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
>       at Weather.js:31

Here is my Weather.js:

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&appid=APIKEY')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({forecasts: response.data.list});
        });
}

render() {

    const projections = this.state.forecasts.map(forecast => {
        return <Subweather
                date={forecast.dt_txt}
                temp={forecast.main.temp}
                key={forecast.id}  /> ;
    });

    const weather = projections[0, 8, 16, 24, 32];

    return (
        <div className={classes.WeatherDiv}>
            {weather}
        </div>
```

Here is what the array looks like when I return it in the console (image attached).[image: Image From Console]

I assumed that since I am mapping this to a new array, the best way to get this value is to use `forecast.main.temp` since the `temp` value is within the `main` but this obviously comes back as undefined so it's not there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `{ console.log(forecast); return ...` Is it what you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forecast` is an array, so you need to access its elements. `main` is a property of each object belonging to this array. You may need to loop through each element to get all the data you need, but for retrieving the first entry you need to access the array element itself before `main` can be referenced:

```
var myTemp = forecast[0].main.temp;
```

Comment: @logos_164 what does `console.log(forecast)` give you inside your function callback before the return?

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer to your error is the asynchronous api call that you make in componentDidMount().

React doesn't guarantee to hold render() from being executed till the api call returns a response and hence your forecasts in state is undefined when render() is executed.

What I suggest is to rather set an initial default state for forecasts in your component so that it renders without any error. And once you receive the response in componentDidMount() your component will anyhow be re-rendered due to setState().